# Azure SQL tools for reports - parametrised stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am thinking of using some Azure services to share SQL reports with external users. And now I am a little bit confused because there seems no good option for the thing I need.

I have an on-premise SQL database with parametrised stored procedure which returns a set of rows like a select statement. The final effect should be a solution which will give external user possibility to execute this stored procedure with provided input parameters and be able to save the results to Excel file.

So I've thought about migrating tables which are used by this procedure to Azure SQL database and then maybe build some application using PowerApp or Functions, but at this moment I am just stuck and don't know from where to start.

Comment: What specifically is Azure lacking that is causing your confusion?

Comment: I don't think it's lacking anything but I just don't know which Azure tools to use to this specific case

Comment: Just create a sql server and sql database in Azure and use it by connecting to it in the same was as you would with any other database.

Comment: Yes, that's an idea, but what if I don't want to move whole database, but only use the local database as a data source ? And another thing is that I need as a final effect a user-friendly tools for external user to execute the stored procedure

Comment: You can use a VNET to connect to your on premises database if that's what you want

Comment: You could also write an API in C# or similar which could call your SP